# Bypass authentication to a specific page via URL access

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an application that has current authentication with require users to login first before accessing the page number.

I want to have the users to bypass authentication for a url with specific page number.

For example, I give them this URL:

`example.com/f?p=100:123123`

If they access page "123123" then it should direct them to the page itself, not requiring login.

I have tried the deep linking feature, but it's not what my expected result, and I don't think oracle apex supports different authentication scheme on each pages

Is this possible, is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: So you intentionally want to build in a security flaw?

Comment: @easleyfixed I'm sorry but what does that exactly mean? Regarding security, the domain can only be accessed within our network or something like that structure. There will be a prompt that the user isn't authorized to access this specific page/url

Comment: On the page designer, set page attributes -> security -> authentication -> 'Page is public'

Comment: Oh I see if there is no external access, then it might be okay.  Just defeating a login system seems like a work around rather than a solution normally.

Answer (score 0):

Set the page attribute: "Security > Authentication" to "Page is public". This should allow the page to come up with the user being prompted for authentication. The user for that session will be "nobody".

Make sure that the following settings are **off**:

- Application > Security Attributes > Authentication > Run on Public Pages
- Application > Security Attributes > Authorization > Run on Public Pages

Comment: Hello, this is what I did. But it doesn't work unfortunately and I think the reason might be because the application uses a custom authentication and everytime the session is not valid it will just direct to login page.

Comment: I want to ask if it's possible maybe through PL/SQL or if there's other workaround that can bypass the authentication scheme on a specific page?

Comment: This should not be related to the authentication scheme. Check my updated answer.

Comment: It's already set to off, I have checked the sentry function and I'm not sure if it could be dynamically done there like using define_user_session() or login() functions of apex. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is not related to the application authorization scheme, nothing needs to be done dynamically. There must be a setting preventing the page as public.
run the page in debug mode. Check debug. Does this give you any clues ?